# How to explore a Common Lisp image

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

Is there a way to explore the current state of a Common Lisp image (i.e. the loaded packages, available symbols, etc.)?

I know about the command `(apropos "foo")`, but I would like to see the current state of the whole image.

Is there such an explorer? I am using SBCL and SLIME (in Emacs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can list all the existing packages with:

```
(list-all-packages)
```

For a given package, you can iterate over all its symbols or its external symbols:

```
(do-symbols (sym package)
  ...)

(do-external-symbols (sym package)
  ...)
```

You can also directly list all symbols in all packages:

```
(do-all-symbols (sym)
  ...)
```

When using Slime, inspecting a symbol with `slime-inspect` gives a summary of all things named after that symbol; for example, if I inspect `'number`, the following is shown:

```
#<SYMBOL {5024C0CF}>
--------------------
Its name is: "NUMBER"
It is unbound.
It has no function value.
It is external to the package: COMMON-LISP [unintern]
Property list: NIL
It names the class NUMBER [remove]
It names a primitive type-specifier.
```

The `NUMBER` and `COMMON-LISP` texts above are also buttons, which you can click to visit the associated value. If you are only using SBCL, the same can be achieved by calling `(find-class symbol nil)` (the NIL indicates that no error should be reported if the symbol does not name  a class), `(symbol-plist symbol)`, etc.

There are some things which cannot be introspected according to the standard, like structs or the list of all user-defined types introduced with `deftype` (maybe other things). Depending on what you want to do, you may need to have a look at an implementation-specific way of doing this.

---

Thanks to David Hodge for pointing out the following:

> A package called repl-utilities from Rob Warnock has a neat function called summary which shows each function, global variable with associated docstrings

Comment: A package called repl-utilities from Rob Warnock has a neat function called summary which shows each function, global variable with associated docstrings

Comment: @DavidHodge Thank you, I added it to the answer so that it stands out

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graphical, web explorer: https://github.com/lokedhs/docbrowser

Once started, it shows a first page with a list of all available packages loaded in the current image. Clicking on a package shows its functions and parameters, with their docstrings, and clicking on one shows its source code.

[image]

A similar one is [livedoc](https://github.com/mmontone/cl-livedocs), more recent and maybe more maintainted.

[image: livedoc package]

By the same proficient lisper, [lisp-system-browser](https://github.com/mmontone/lisp-system-browser) is a Slime extension (for Emacs then) that will act as a Smalltalk-ish browser: it will list all the available systems (think Quicklisp libraries) in a pane, when you click on a system it will list the available functions, macros and variables.

[image]][3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mmontone/lisp-system-browser/master/system-browser.gif)